# Disqus script not well formed

Tags: javascript

Blogger keeps telling me that the script is not well formed, I have tried to test it in firebug, but I do not seem to detect the issue. Help out

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    (function() {
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        var query = '?';
        for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            if(links[i].href.indexOf('#disqus_thread') >= 0) {
                query += 'url' + i + '=' + encodeURIComponent(links[i].href) + '&';
            }
        }
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/hi-tech/get_num_replies.js' + query + '"></' + 'script>');
    })();
</script>
```

Comment: Your browser isn't parsing the template as XML, so Firebug wouldn't encounter the XML errors in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [HTML compatibility guidelines for XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4).

Move your JS to an external script file, or wrap it in a CDATA block.